# I am trying to integrate OKTA React native but I only have SAML file. How do I get oidc values from it?

Tags: okta, okta-signin-widget, okta-react-native

I am working for a company X and our product will have a OKTA login for employees of company Y.

When I looked online for react native login, I got a link where I will need **oidc** config values like
issuer:  'https://y.okta.com',
clientId: 'rexc01y7yh23OyOOe2p8',
redirectUrl: "com.okta.y:/callback",
endSessionRedirectUri: 'com.okta.y:/callback',
scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'offline_access'],
requireHardwareBackedKeyStore: false,
discoveryUri: 'https://y.okta.com/oauth2/default'

But all I got was a SAML file.

1. Am I suppose to get **oidc** values from SAML file?
   or
2. Is there a way to implement OKTA inside my app for company x using SAML file?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use react native, you need to create OIDC application in Okta, which will have as a result all parameters, which you are looking for: client_id, issuer...

Comment: Is there a hacky way to use OKTA saml end point to login inside react native?

Comment: Okta SAML app config has "ACS URL", where the SAML assertion is sent after you successfully authenticate yourself to Okta. So if it's not your app, then no luck for you